# Dice prediction game for python

Tags: python, prediction, dice

I'm writing a python program that asks you to predict a die. You start with 5 euro and you earn 5 euro if you win, lose 1 euro if you're 1 off and lose 3 euro if you're more than 1 off.

```
def main():

    while True:
        saldo = 5
        y = input("[R]oll or [S]top")
        if y == "r" :
            p = input("What is your prediction?")
            from random import randint
            x = randint(1, 6)
            print(x)
            if p == x:
                saldo = saldo +5  
            elif p == int(x-1) or p == int(x+1):
                saldo = saldo -1
            else:
                saldo = saldo -3
            print ("saldo is " , saldo)
        elif y == "s" :
            saldo = saldo
            print ("eindsaldo is " , saldo)
            return
        else:
            print ("Enter r or s")

main()
```

The random part is working but not the saldo part and I can't figure out what is going wrong. I am new at Python but got some experience on Javascript and other basic programming languages. This looks like it should work though.

Comment: place your saldo=5 befor the while function

Answer (score 2):

Your `saldo` is initialised inside the while loop.

This means every time you start at the beginning of the loop, your saldos are set to 5.

```
def main()
    saldo = 5
    while True:
        y = input("[R]oll or [S]top")
        ...
```

Move the `saldo = 5` outside the while loop.

Comment: I'd prefer that you say that `saldo` is *initialised* rather than defined.

Comment: @quamrana Updated

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the below code. I took the liberty to make additional changes to make the whole thing more Pythonic and efficient.

Update2: I took the liberty to make some small adjustments (Antonvbr)

```
from random import randint  # 1

def main(saldo):            

    while True:
        y = input("[R]oll or [S]top").lower()  # 3

        if y == "r" :
            p = input("What is your prediction?") #4
            while p not in list("123456"):
                print("Enter a valid number 1-6")
                p = input("What is your prediction?")
            p = int(p) # convert to integer
            x = randint(1, 6)
            print(x)
            if p == x:
                saldo += 5  
            elif abs(p-x) == 1:
                saldo -= 1
            else:
                saldo -= 3
            print ("saldo is {}".format(saldo))  # 5

        elif y == "s" :
            print ("stop! saldo is {}".format(saldo))
            return saldo

        else:
            print ("Enter R/r or S/s") # Not case sensitivt anymore

startsaldo = 5
saldo = main(startsaldo) #2
```

Explanation:

1. you do not want to import on every iteration, import functions are always made first
2. as mentioned by others `saldo` needs to be initialized once only. Normally parameters like these are injected in the function and returned back when the function quits.
3. you are asking for `"R"` or `"S"` but comparing against `"r"` and `"s"`. In Python, case matters.
4. you only want inputs 1-6 to be valid list("123456") returns ["1","2...]
   and then we convert that to an int
5. string formatting is a very valuable tool to learn.

Also generally, `var = var + 1` is written like `var += 1` in Python. Same applies with `-` too.

Comment: Actually: 1/ the import should be outside the function, 2/ `x` is an int so `int(x-1)` and `int(x+1)` is redundant, and 3/  `p == x-1 or p == x+1` can be simplified to `abs(p-x) == 1`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I also noticed that and the try accept for int was breaking the loop. I took the liberty to "correct".

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers for the import it depends on what else is outside the function when it comes to where you put it. as far as the input it concerned I was referring to the `p==x` but you are right, the `int(x-1)..` is no longer needed.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Sorry took the liberty to change some more things. I had a similar answer coming in and thought I'd just change yours instead of posting something "similar". +1

Comment: @Ev.Kounis well there are a very few corner cases where importing from within a function makes sense but those are exceptions really - the official BestPractice(tm) is to have all your imports at the very start of your module, .